# How to add new language to NLLB tokenizer in Huggingface?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers, machine-translation

No Language Left Behind (NLLB) is the machine translation model available on https://huggingface.co/facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M

It supports a list of languages but to add a new language in the tokenizer, the follow code runs successfully but the language token didn't get add to the tokenizer object.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
tokenizer.additional_special_tokens.append('aym_Latn')

print('aym_Latn' in tokenizer.additional_special_tokens)

tokenizer
```

[out]:

```
False

NllbTokenizerFast(name_or_path='facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M', vocab_size=256204, model_max_length=1024, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'bos_token': '<s>', 'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'sep_token': '</s>', 'pad_token': '<pad>', 'cls_token': '<s>', 'mask_token': AddedToken("<mask>", rstrip=False, lstrip=True, single_word=False, normalized=True), 
  'additional_special_tokens': ['ace_Arab', 'ace_Latn', 'acm_Arab', 'acq_Arab', 'aeb_Arab', 'afr_Latn', 'ajp_Arab', 'aka_Latn', 'amh_Ethi', 'apc_Arab', 'arb_Arab', 'ars_Arab', 'ary_Arab', 'arz_Arab', 'asm_Beng', 'ast_Latn', 'awa_Deva', 'ayr_Latn', 'azb_Arab', 'azj_Latn', 'bak_Cyrl', 'bam_Latn', 'ban_Latn', 'bel_Cyrl', 'bem_Latn', 'ben_Beng', 'bho_Deva', 'bjn_Arab', 'bjn_Latn', 'bod_Tibt', 'bos_Latn', 'bug_Latn', 'bul_Cyrl', 'cat_Latn', 'ceb_Latn', 'ces_Latn', 'cjk_Latn', 'ckb_Arab', 'crh_Latn', 'cym_Latn', 'dan_Latn', 'deu_Latn', 'dik_Latn', 'dyu_Latn', 'dzo_Tibt', 'ell_Grek', 'eng_Latn', 'epo_Latn', 'est_Latn', 'eus_Latn', 'ewe_Latn', 'fao_Latn', 'pes_Arab', 'fij_Latn', 'fin_Latn', 'fon_Latn', 'fra_Latn', 'fur_Latn', 'fuv_Latn', 'gla_Latn', 'gle_Latn', 'glg_Latn', 'grn_Latn', 'guj_Gujr', 'hat_Latn', 'hau_Latn', 'heb_Hebr', 'hin_Deva', 'hne_Deva', 'hrv_Latn', 'hun_Latn', 'hye_Armn', 'ibo_Latn', 'ilo_Latn', 'ind_Latn', 'isl_Latn', 'ita_Latn', 'jav_Latn', 'jpn_Jpan', 'kab_Latn', 'kac_Latn', 'kam_Latn', 'kan_Knda', 'kas_Arab', 'kas_Deva', 'kat_Geor', 'knc_Arab', 'knc_Latn', 'kaz_Cyrl', 'kbp_Latn', 'kea_Latn', 'khm_Khmr', 'kik_Latn', 'kin_Latn', 'kir_Cyrl', 'kmb_Latn', 'kon_Latn', 'kor_Hang', 'kmr_Latn', 'lao_Laoo', 'lvs_Latn', 'lij_Latn', 'lim_Latn', 'lin_Latn', 'lit_Latn', 'lmo_Latn', 'ltg_Latn', 'ltz_Latn', 'lua_Latn', 'lug_Latn', 'luo_Latn', 'lus_Latn', 'mag_Deva', 'mai_Deva', 'mal_Mlym', 'mar_Deva', 'min_Latn', 'mkd_Cyrl', 'plt_Latn', 'mlt_Latn', 'mni_Beng', 'khk_Cyrl', 'mos_Latn', 'mri_Latn', 'zsm_Latn', 'mya_Mymr', 'nld_Latn', 'nno_Latn', 'nob_Latn', 'npi_Deva', 'nso_Latn', 'nus_Latn', 'nya_Latn', 'oci_Latn', 'gaz_Latn', 'ory_Orya', 'pag_Latn', 'pan_Guru', 'pap_Latn', 'pol_Latn', 'por_Latn', 'prs_Arab', 'pbt_Arab', 'quy_Latn', 'ron_Latn', 'run_Latn', 'rus_Cyrl', 'sag_Latn', 'san_Deva', 'sat_Beng', 'scn_Latn', 'shn_Mymr', 'sin_Sinh', 'slk_Latn', 'slv_Latn', 'smo_Latn', 'sna_Latn', 'snd_Arab', 'som_Latn', 'sot_Latn', 'spa_Latn', 'als_Latn', 'srd_Latn', 'srp_Cyrl', 'ssw_Latn', 'sun_Latn', 'swe_Latn', 'swh_Latn', 'szl_Latn', 'tam_Taml', 'tat_Cyrl', 'tel_Telu', 'tgk_Cyrl', 'tgl_Latn', 'tha_Thai', 'tir_Ethi', 'taq_Latn', 'taq_Tfng', 'tpi_Latn', 'tsn_Latn', 'tso_Latn', 'tuk_Latn', 'tum_Latn', 'tur_Latn', 'twi_Latn', 'tzm_Tfng', 'uig_Arab', 'ukr_Cyrl', 'umb_Latn', 'urd_Arab', 'uzn_Latn', 'vec_Latn', 'vie_Latn', 'war_Latn', 'wol_Latn', 'xho_Latn', 'ydd_Hebr', 'yor_Latn', 'yue_Hant', 'zho_Hans', 'zho_Hant', 'zul_Latn']}, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
```

There's some solution on https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/247 but note that if you do something like overriding the additional special tokens, the original ones will be lost, i.e.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': ['aym_Latn']})

print('aym_Latn' in tokenizer.additional_special_tokens)
tokenizer
```

[out]:

```
True

NllbTokenizerFast(name_or_path='facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M', vocab_size=256204, model_max_length=1024, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'bos_token': '<s>', 'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'sep_token': '</s>', 'pad_token': '<pad>', 'cls_token': '<s>', 'mask_token': AddedToken("<mask>", rstrip=False, lstrip=True, single_word=False, normalized=True), 
  'additional_special_tokens': ['aym_Latn']}, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
```

**How to add new language to NLLB tokenizer in Huggingface?**

My questions in parts are:

- (part1) How to add the special tokens for new languages? (without forgetting all the other languages it's trained on)
- (part2) After adding the special tokens, are there additional steps to properly tokenize inputs? E.g. change/set the language token assignment function
- (part3) After adding the special tokens and any additional steps, when processing the inputs, should the special token be pre-pended in the raw string? Or is there a special function in NLLB tokenizer to automatically add it in when initializing the tokenizer?

---

The desired goal is to be able to do this with pipeline automatically detecting the new added language after fine-tuning the model.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, pipeline

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")

translator = pipeline(‘translation’, 
    model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, 
    src_lang="aym_Latn", tgt_lang="spa_Latn", 
    max_length = 512
)

pipeline("Phisqha alwa pachaw sartapxta ukatx utaj jak’an 3 millas ukaruw muytir sarapxta.")
```

The pipeline method might not be possible since there might be some implicit function controlling how the tokenizer interacts with the languages, in that case, at least this should work:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, pipeline

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")

# In this case, how do we add the `src_lang` and `tgt_lang`?
text = "Phisqha alwa pachaw sartapxta ukatx utaj jak’an 3 millas ukaruw muytir sarapxta."

model.generate(**tokenizer([text], return_tensors="pt", padding=True))
```

**In the case, how do we add the `src_lang` and `tgt_lang`?**

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break these down into 3 separate questions...

## Part 1: How to add the special tokens for new languages?

The issue you're seeing is that calling `tokenizer.add_special_tokens` doesn't append the new special tokens to the existing ones, it replaces them. To append, you should *first* retrieve the existing special tokens, add your new token to the list, and then call `add_special_tokens` with the updated list.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
new_special_tokens = tokenizer.additional_special_tokens + ['aym_Latn']
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': new_special_tokens})

print('aym_Latn' in tokenizer.additional_special_tokens)
```

## Part 2: After adding the special tokens, are there additional steps to properly tokenize inputs?

Once the special tokens have been added, you don't need to do anything else to properly tokenize the inputs. The tokenizer will recognize these new special tokens and handle them appropriately during tokenization. Remember though that the model must be trained or fine-tuned to understand this new token.

## Part 3: After adding the special tokens and any additional steps, when processing the inputs, should the special token be pre-pended in the raw string? Or is there a special function in NLLB tokenizer to automatically add it in when initializing the tokenizer?

For the NLLB model, you would need to prepend the special token to your input string.

```
input_string = "This is a test."
language_token = "aym_Latn"
tokenized_input = tokenizer(language_token + input_string)
```

Edit to respond to OP Questions...

> Won't new_special_tokens = tokenizer.additional_special_tokens +
> ['aym_Latn'] shift the vocab IDs? And would that affect the main
> tokenizer vocabs IDs? If not, there must be some sort of limit to how
> many tokens we can add, before it affects the main tokenizer's ID,
> right?

When you add a new token using `tokenizer.add_tokens()` or `tokenizer.add_special_tokens()`, the Hugging Face's tokenizer does not shift the IDs of the existing vocabulary. It appends the new tokens to the end of the vocabulary.

If your original tokenizer had a vocabulary size of `n`, and you add `k` new tokens, the new tokens will be assigned IDs `n`, `n+1`, ..., `n+k-1` etc.

There's no hard limit to the number of tokens you can add, but there are a few considerations: Memory, model selection (I think BERT based models are limited to 512), and performance (kind of tied to memory).

> Also do we also prepend the target language tag to make sure the model
> reads the input properly and treat them as special tokens?

Language tags can be used with some models to provide context, if its needed. Some models (like mBERT), this doesn't matter. Adding tags won't automatically enable the model to understand a new language. However, in your case it may? It's really use case specific tbh.

Comment: Won't `new_special_tokens = tokenizer.additional_special_tokens + ['aym_Latn']` shift the vocab IDs? And would that affect the main tokenizer vocabs IDs? If not, there must be some sort of limit to how many tokens we can add, before it affects the main tokenizer's ID, right?

Comment: Also do we also prepend the target language tag to make sure the model reads the input properly and treat them as special tokens?

Comment: I addressed your questions in my edit @alvas

Comment: I've granted you the bounty so that it don't go to waste =) But I think there's some bits that can be improved in terms of documenting the NLLB model and how it interacts with the tokenizer. I'll try to dig deeper and help improve the answer when I'm free.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any other questions, good luck :) @alvas

Answer (score 0):

1. On adding special tokens for new languages:
   Right now what works for me is to load the tokenizer like:

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M", additional_special_tokens=["aym_Latn"])
```

`additional_special_tokens` is described in the HF Tokenizer [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html) as an optional initialization parameter for the `transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer` class (which is the base class for all HF tokenizers). @artemis's answer didn't work for me- previous language tokens kept getting deleted.

2. Depending on your situation, you might need to update the vocabulary of your tokenizer with tokens from your new language. If not, your tokenizer would output a lot of `<unk>` tokens because although you'll obtain valid token strings from e.g.

```py
tokenizer.tokenize("Phisqha alwa pachaw sartapxta ukatx utaj jak’an 3.")
```

the tokenizer doesn't have any ids stored for those tokens. This is especially likely if you're working with a language which uses a completely different writing script from those in the tokenizer's vocabulary- new characters, etc.

To add new tokens,

```
#Tokenize all of the data with which you intend to update the vocabulary.
new_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("Phisqha alwa pachaw sartapxta ukatx utaj jak’an 3.") 

tokenizer.add_tokens(new_tokens)
```