# Adding a new language to facebook/m2m100_418M model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I am trying to add a new language to the pretrained M2M model ([facebook/m2m100_418M](https://huggingface.co/facebook/m2m100_418M)) but I really don't know how to start. Is there anyway that i can add a new language to the model and eliminate those languages from the model that im not going to use?

In [In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199337/how-to-add-new-language-to-nllb-tokenizer-in-huggingface) they explain how to do this with NLLB in a very simple manner but it does not work for M2M.

Also this [repository](https://github.com/BramVanroy/multilingual-text-to-amr) explains how to do it with MBART but im not sure how to addapt it.